# Soft attention from scratch for video sequences

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, attention-model

I am trying to implement soft attention for video sequences classification. As there are a lot of implementations and examples about NLP so I tried following this schema but for video [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFHkd.png). Basically a LSTM with an Attention Model in between.
[image]

*[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFHkd.png) https://blog.heuritech.com/2016/01/20/attention-mechanism/*

My code for my attention layer is the following which I am not sure it is implemented correctly.

```
def attention_layer(self, input, context):

    # Input is a Tensor: [batch_size, lstm_units]
    # Input (Seq_length, batch_size, lstm_units)
    # Context is a LSTMStateTuple: [batch_size, lstm_units]. Hidden_state, output = StateTuple

    hidden_state, _ = context
    weights_y = tf.get_variable("att_weights_Y", [self.lstm_units, self.lstm_units], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    weights_c = tf.get_variable("att_weights_c", [self.lstm_units, self.lstm_units], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    z_ = []

    for feat in input:
        # Equation => M  = tanh(Wc c + Wy y)
        Wcc = tf.matmul(hidden_state, weights_c)
        Wyy = tf.matmul(feat, weights_y)

        m = tf.add(Wcc, Wyy)
        m = tf.tanh(m, name='M_matrix')

        # Equation => s = softmax(m)
        s = tf.nn.softmax(m, name='softmax_att')
        z = tf.multiply(feat, s)

        z_.append(z)

    out = tf.stack(z_, axis=1)
    out = tf.reduce_sum(out, 1)
    return out, s
```

So, adding this layer in between my LSTMs (or at the begining of my 2 LSTM) makes the training so slow. More specifically, it takes a lot of time when I declare my optimizer:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

My questions are:

1. Is the implementation correct? If it is, is there a way to optimize it in order to make it train properly?
2. I was not able to make it work with the seq2seq APIs. Is there any API with Tensorflow that allows me tackle this specific issue?
3. Does it actually makes sense to use this for sequence classification?

Comment: Did you solve it or find it out how to implement the attention?